# How to assign char[] to null inside the struct

Tags: c, string, struct, char, filesystems

I m trying to assign null to char name[] inside the struct; however, it not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define name_size  30   
#define bloc_entry_number  20   
#define file_list_number 10
#define direction_list_number 10

struct File { 
    char name[name_size]; 
    int block_entry[bloc_entry_number]; 
};

struct Direction{    
    char name[name_size];
    int current_index;
    int previous_index;

    struct File* file_list[file_list_number]; 
    int file_list_tracking[file_list_number]; 

    struct Direction* next_entry_direction[direction_list_number]; 
    int next_entry_direction_tracking[direction_list_number];
};

struct Block{
    int index; 
    int size_remain; 
};

int main(){
    struct Direction *dir = (struct Direction*) malloc(sizeof(struct Direction));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ){
        dir->next_entry_direction[i]->name[0] = '\0'; // error occur here
        printf("%s",dir->next_entry_direction[i]->name);// error occur here;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i m not able to assign NULL to char name[];
how can i fix it? i have already try name[0] = '\0', name = NULL, strcpy(name,NULL)

Comment: Try not to use fixed-length character buffers like that but instead dynamically allocated `char*` buffers that can be the precise length needed. This not only wastes space, but invites overflow bugs.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you `strcpy` a `NULL` pointer? That's not a valid pointer. You can't "assign" `NULL` to a non-pointer type.

Comment: I'm also super confused why this struct has ten of itself inside itself, which means that those too have ten more pointers to ten more entries. Did you mean to declare an array of them separately from the main struct, or is this a linked structure of some sort?

Comment: @tadman i m trying to create a FAT-table

Comment: Each element in that internal array *must* be allocated individually if before those pointers can be exercised. You allocate for a single `Direction` structure and then go about hammering the invalid pointers it contains. You'll need a proper `make_Direction()` type function to allocate this correctly as well as a corresponding `free_Direction()` that will release the memory correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set it to NULL. It's an array and not a pointer. What you can do is this:

```
dir->next_entry_direction[i]->name[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: it continues giving me the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

Comment: @ChenerZhang That's an error I cannot produce with the code you have posted. Please read [ask], create a [mre] and post a new question.

Comment: @ChenerZhang Well, you cannot set an array to NULL. That's simply not possible. I suggest you create a NEW question with the actual problem you're trying to solve. You got to have a reason to want to do what I have said is impossible. Don't edit this question since it would likely invalidate this answer.